# How to fix thread error in Xcode?

Tags: ios, multithreading, runtime-error

I am newly in iOS development. **I have error like this... "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1".** How to fix this error :

[image]

This is header(.h) file

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
    - (IBAction)tekan:(id)sender;

    @end
```

And this is implementation(.m) file

```
    //
//  ViewController.m
//  Example1
//
//  Created by Andika Kurniawan on 10/6/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Indonative. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize passwordTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.passwordTextField.delegate = self;
    self.usernameTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)tekan:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *helloEarthInputAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                         initWithTitle:@"Name!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: %@", passwordTextField.text]
                                         delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // Display this message.
    [helloEarthInputAlert show];
}
@end
```

Above codes is my source code. 
**I want to fix thread error,** but I confuse... because I don't know what error which exist in my source code.
Outlet and actions in this app haven't error

Comment: I think you just need to click on the blue mark inside which 34 of line number 34 is written. It is a break point that is causing your code to stop at line 34.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]You dont have an error. You only have a break point. Press play in the debug menu (above the console and where you have the values in memory) and the app should continue the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to click on the blue mark inside which 34 of line number 34 is written. It is a break point that is causing your code to stop at line 34.

Thanks

Comment: thanks, but below answerer answer my question detail

Comment: Sure, no problem with that. I just wanted to help. :)

Comment: You have nothing to apologise bro. That guy worked harder than me, I was lazy. I up voted his answer myself.